# not getting captcha with Firebase phone Authentication in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

When i use firebase phone authentication in angular application, i am not getting captcha.

Here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

@Component({
      selector: "app-login",
      templateUrl: "./login.page.html",
      styleUrls: ["./login.page.scss"]
    })
    export class LoginPage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

          confirmationResult: firebase.auth.ConfirmationResult;
          recaptchaVerifier: firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier;
          constructor(){
    }
            ngAfterViewInit() {
                this.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
                  "recaptcha-container",
                  {
                    size: "normal",
                    callback: response => {
                      // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
                      if (response) {

                      }
                    },
                    "expired-callback": () => {
                      // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
                    }
                  }
                );
                this.recaptchaVerifier.render();
              }
    }
```

Here are libs "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0" and "firebase": "^7.14.0".Before 7.14.0 it was coming.when i run i am getting "cannot read property RecaptchaVerifier of undefined".How could i get captcha with above code.Is there anything i am missing.Thanks in advance.

Comment: in angular you should be using `angularfireauth` ! `new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier` is for pure web

Comment: I wanted to use firebase phone authentication in angular but angular fire auth module does not contains RecaptchaVerifier

Comment: i dont think they have support for this. look at this issue. its quite same as yours => https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1466

Comment: I changed the import statement and then it started working fine. import * as firebase from "firebase/app" to import * as firebase from "firebase"